# App Store Future Release Set Date

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Is there any way to change the release date of my current release that's currently "Waiting for Review"?  I found "Set availability date" in Rights and Pricing, but that says it will change the availability date for ALL versions, including the one currently in the App Store and my current one will be removed.

Basically I want my update to just be released when I say (kind of like the option when you first upload the binary).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you marked the app as ready for upload in iTunes Connect you were presented with an option to release immediately or hold for developer release.  If it hasn't been in "waiting for review" very long, you could just reject the binary and re-upload, this time picking the "hold for developer release" option.